# How to cite two references within dash?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, oneside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\title{\normalfont{Technical Report: Loren Ipsum}} 

\author{{Alex Murphy}}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Abstract} 

Test cite \cite{key1, key2}  \lipsum[1] % Dummy text


\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{key1} John Doe {\em Title and stuff}  2013.
\bibitem{key2} John Doe {\em Title and stuff}  2014.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

However, I want to show citation like `[1-2]` instead of `[1, 2]`. **How can I do so?**

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: @DG' I have updated the post. Thought it was easy to understand what I was asking for by experts.

Comment: the cite package can compress cites, but it will do it only do for three and more cites, not for two.